# Is angular cli version and angular version the same?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This might be a silly question but I didn't find any clear answer for this.

Is the angular cli version and angular version the same.

When I ask any one the version angular they simply ask me to check it by using ng -v

This actually shows me the angular cli version

So what would be the angular version (2,3,4,5)??

Answer (score 2):

All angular related packages (RxJs,AngularMaterial, ngrx and the ngCLI) had also adopted the version of the main Angular framework.

The case with the ngCli was that it jumped from version 1.7.4 to 6.0.

Comment: Can there be an angular cli version of 1.6 and angular version inside it as 5

Comment: Absolutely, that was the only possible combination case until few weeks ago

Comment: So, to update the angular version, I just change the version number inside the package.json and npm install, Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite, look at the official migration guide https://update.angular.io , i advice you to follow it step by step + look at rxjs migration guide  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md